# Two versions of python in one computer

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I have Python 3.8 (32-bit) in my computer, I use Pycharm and also jupyter notebook.
I need to install Python 3.6 (64-bit) because I need to work with tensorflow and it only works with Python 3.6(64-bit)

Can I have two versions of python together? And How can change and work with two python versions in pycharm and jupyter?

Comment: You can definitely install 2 different versions of Python, look for the settings on either one of your IDEs and find an option for something along the lines of 'compiler/interpreter path'. Following that, select your path to the python executable.

Comment: simply install the required version in system and in IDE set the required interpreter for your project/work

Comment: If you're on macOs/Linux, check out pyenv for easily managing python versions

Comment: I'm on Windows. In pycharm there is a way to change it in setting but can I change it for jupyter notebook too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred way to use python virtual environments now is [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

You can install any number of python versions on your windows, though please also install the py launcher that it comes with. This makes it easy to launch whichever python version you want through the commandline, with no need to rely on PATH nonsense.

If you've the `py` launcher you can simply launch your desired python version using-

```
py -3.6-64
```

The above will launch the 64 bit version of python 3.6 (if installed).

Now, you'll also want to use a virtual env and point pycharm to the venv. To make a `venv`, go to your project directory (preferably) and do-

```
> py -3.6-64 -m venv name_of_venv
```

This will make a venv named of `name_of_venv` in your project directory and the python version will be 3.6 64 bit.

Now whenever you need to do any python commands, you no longer need to do `py -version`, you can just do `python` and even use `pip` - BUT before that, you need to activate the `venv`

```
> & '.\name_of_venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1'
```

Now you can do normal python operations as long within this venv and it'll all target 3.6 64 bit (or any other version you choose to build the `venv` with).

To deactivate (though you don't really have to) - you can just type `deactivate` in the terminal.

Pycharm can be configured with this `venv` as simply as just pointing to it. You simply have to go to **Add python interpreter** and choose **Virtualenv Environment**

Comment: I just ask to make sure, can I use venv in windows too?

Comment: @A.mh yes this answer is window specific

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have multiple Python versions. You can add dependency like `python3.6`.

You can also use [pyenv](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/). It provides excellent facility to manage various python versions on your machine.

Comment: I'm on windows and I guess pyenv is for mac and linux, right?

Comment: True, but a similar tool is also available for windows, pyenv-win (https://pypi.org/project/pyenv-win/). Can it be helpful to you ?