# How to install and use both python 3.8 and 3.7 on windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-install

How to use Python 3.8 and 3.7 on Windows 10. I want to make two applications, but one requires 3.8 and another one 3.7.
So how to manage both versions in one Windows 10.

Comment: Comprehensive explanation https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

Comment: If you really require to manage multiple versions I believe you can install **Anaconda**

Comment: it helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62428732/two-versions-of-python-in-one-computer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should just install Python 3.7 and Python 3.8 and make sure that the Python Launcher for Windows is also installed (this is the default).

Then you could run your scripts using `py -3.7 main.py` or `py -3.8 main.py` to run main.py using Python versions 3.7 or 3.8, respectively.

Alternatively (even better actually), you could write the required Python version in the first line of your Python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
```

Note that this **must** be the first line of the script, otherwise it doesn't work. Now just running `py main.py` would automatically select the correct Python version to execute the script.

NB: If the script is executed in Linux it would also run with the correct Python version.

Answer (score 0):

Using virtual environment you can install several python versions and more importantly you can install different modules version for each of those python revision (the main reason for running different python version is that some modules are not (yet) compatible with recent python releases).
You can check how to create/update and activate different virtual environment [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/venv.html).
Those env can use their own python version or share it, it is chosen at creation time (the python version you use when creating the env is the one that will be used any time you activate the env).